# How to prevent screen tearing when using triple buffering in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferstrategy

I'm trying to draw a simple shape on the screen using the *Swing* library and the `BufferStrategy` class. However, when using `BufferStrategy` with three buffer areas, screen tearing occurs, but not when using two buffer areas. Does anyone know what's causing this behavior?

Here is my code:

```java
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Shape extends JFrame {
    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    public Shape() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000, 800);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(canvas);
        setVisible(true);
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3); //    Screen tearing occurs
        // canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);    Would work properly

        while (true) {
            BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
            Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            g.dispose();
            bufferStrategy.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Shape();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: You could try 4 buffers and see if that works.  I don't know why you would need more than two.  The `while(true)` is suspicious to me.  Perhaps you need to use a `Timer` to give the buffer strategy time to work.  A Swing drawing `JPanel` is double-buffered by default.